# Increase Alphanumeric VARCHAR Entry by Value 1?

Tags: mysql

On an old project because of not thought through design I have a column which actually should be set to auto_increment, though it cannot be because it are alphanumeric entries as follows:

```
c01
c02
c03
```

(c99 would continue to c100 and more), the letter happened in the past and it would require to overhaul the system to take it out, thus I rather prefer this workaround.

Now I need a way to imitate the `auto_increment` functionality with the SQL statement myself, my own attempt has gotten as far as the following:

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag_id, tag_name, tag_description, added_by_user_id, creation_date, last_edited) VALUES (SELECT(MAX(tag_id)+1), 

'Love', 'All about love', 7, now(), 0);
```

This one does not work as is, though the idea was to select the highest entry in the column "tag_id" and then simply increase it by the value 1.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

By the way I am also not sure if you simply can increase an alphanumeric entry through this way, though I know it can be done, I just don't know how.

Comment: Are you certain that all identity keys are always of the form `c##..`?

Comment: Do you have to go to c100 or could you just go to d01?  or how about c9A.c9b,c9c,c9d... then caa cab cac.. cba..cbb..ccc... etc.  Key's really shouldn't be intelligent.  They just need to be unique.

Comment: Another way to approach this would be to separate this into two columns and use `CONCAT(id_char, id_number)` on the two columns instead of just `SELECT`ing the id. Depending on the circumstances, this change may not take too much work to make. Also, depending on the circumstances this might leave you with a pretty efficient system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to safely get the largest integer value of a tag id of the form `c##..`, you could use the following expression:

```
max( convert( substring(tag_id, 2) , unsigned integer) )
^^^ largest   ^^^^^^^^^ after 'c'    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ convert to positive number
```

Then your insert statement would look something like this:

```
set @newid = convert(
              (select 
               max(convert( (substring(tag_id, 2)) , unsigned integer))+1
               from tags), char(10)
            );

set @newid = if(length(@newid) = 1, concat('0', @newid), @newid);
set @newid = concat('c', @newid);

INSERT INTO tags (tag_id, tag_name, tag_description, added_by_user_id,
                  creation_date, last_edited)
VALUES (@newid, 'Love', 'All about love', 7, now(), '2012-04-15');
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bd9f/1

Answer (score 1):

this will increase from c01 to c02 to c03 ... to c99 to c100 to c101 ... to c999 to c1000 etc.

```
set @nextID = (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`tag_id`, 1, 1), IF(CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(SUBSTRING(`tag_id`, 2)
AS UNSIGNED)) < 2, LPAD(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(`tag_id`, 2) AS UNSIGNED) + 1 AS CHAR), 2,
'0'), CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(`tag_id`, 2) AS UNSIGNED) + 1 AS CHAR))) FROM `tags` ORDER BY
`tag_id` DESC LIMIT 1);


INSERT INTO tags (tag_id, tag_name, tag_description, added_by_user_id,
creation_date, last_edited) VALUES (@nextID, 'Love', 'All about love', 7, NOW(), null);
```